# WooCommerce order - action hook just before forwarding to paypal

Tags: woocommerce, hook, action, checkout, orders

My problem is that I want to run function (send email) just after client click on #place_order button in WooCommerce and before redirection to payment processor (PayPal, Przelewy24).

I tested and hooks are working for me, Im just looking for suitable action hook.
Some of hooks are working for methods like transfer or cheque, but i can't find right one for my needs (before redirection to payment processor)

I've already tried these hooks:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 1  );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 1  );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_process', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 1  );     
    add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 1  );

    add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 1  );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 1  );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_submit', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 1  );

    add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 1  );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_processing', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 1  );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold_to_completed', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 1  );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_processing', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 1  );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_completed', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 1  );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing', array( $this, 'trigger' ), 1  );
```

Comment: Your question details are not enough deep to see how you are making this testing around looking for the right hook to trigger an email notification… Is this used in a custom plugin or where and how? Which is the email notification you are trying to trigger? Normally **you should provide the shortest code necessary to reproduce your tries in the question itself**… So please update your question.